# No WiFi on my laptop

Tags: linux, iwlwifi

I am using linux mint rosa. Wireless is Intel AC 8260 WiFi+bluetooth

Intel dont appear to have any linux drivers for this module only all flavours of windows.

Can I get this module working?

Comment: Probably. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/729212/install-intel-ac-8260-wireless-drivers-offline) may help.

Comment: What is the output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`?

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)

Comment: I am using a dongle for WiFi

Comment: I believe to recall an issue I had with my laptop. If it is a Realtek chip, you maybe need to enable the non-free repositories of your distro and install a package called `firmware-realtek`.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

A brief search found me [this link](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html).

As Intel says you simply need to download it and extract it to your /lib/firmware folder. To do that, run the following commands as root:

To become root login as root or issue the `su` command and type in the root password.

```
tar -xzf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
cp -R iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0 /lib/firmware/
```

I am not sure whether it is that easy, but it is worth a try. Also Intel provides general information about setting up your WiFi hardware.

If you can't succeed with the [link](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) above look at [this link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=209496) instead. It's basically the same problem, but a different approach.

Let me know how you did and feel free to ask if you need more assistance.

Comment: Thanks I have downloaded the file , now I need to find out how to copy the file to my /lib firmware folder. I tried copy and paste but paste is grayed out.

Comment: You need root privileges to do that. The most simple way is to open a terminal, run the `su` command, type the root password and then use the following command: `cp firmware-file /lib/firmware/`. I will append that to my answer also.

Answer (score 0):

According to [intel-linux-driver](https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking/000005511.html) you need to download `iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz` , extract it and copy  the files into `/lib/firmware` using the following command:

```
cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```